# How do I test my Google Wallet integration when I can't "purchase from myself" in sandbox?

Tags: android-pay

I'm integrating google wallet with a php-game. I've come to the part where I want to test if my postback-script does it's job, but I can't seem to find any information on how to make a test purchase. I get this error when I try:

[image]

I'm in the sandbox so I don't understand why this is happening. Help?

Comment: isnt there any possibility of dummy users, like facebook provides them?

Comment: I've tried searching for it but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Updated to encompass comments/discussion:

Create a [***new* sandbox buyer** account](https://wallet-web.sandbox.google.com/) - aka a *new* Google Account/email address.

It's a dummy account so you **don't** provide *real data* nor real credit cards - re: use [test cards](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/testing)

- accounts must be distinct - you cannot use the *same* sandbox Seller/Merchant account for your buyer account (that is what the error is saying).
- use a different browser (no pre-exsting/seller auth data/cookie) to test the purchase process using your *buyer sandbox account* (or if using Chrome open up an *incognito* window)

Hth.

Comment: Looks like that's the one I've been using, and it gives me the same error.

Comment: @L42 doubtful - you have a **sandbox merchant** account, which is distinct/different from a **sandbox buyer** account. Also, you'll have to use different browsers for testing, or if you're using chrome - go *incognito* for buyer testing (no pre-auth/cookies). If all else fails, just create a new **sandbox buyer** account - it shouldn't matter (I do it myself so I can have test buyers from different countries). HTH

Comment: @L42 Addendum: use a new/different email addy for your sandbox buyer account.

Comment: How can I create a new buyer account without creating a new (real) google account as well? It looks like following the link you first posted takes me to a screen where I can login to a google account or create a new one. If I login with my google account I'm taken to what appears to be my sandbox buyer account, but might be my merchant account.

Comment: Just to be clear:

Clicking the link you first posted gets me to: https://wallet-web.sandbox.google.com/manage/#transactions:

I've used this page to find my seller identification and secret: https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/settings.html

I'm using both of these links while being logged in to my own google account.

Comment: @L42 Yes you will have to create a **new** buyer/Google account (sandbox). _You cannot buy from yourself_ == _you cannot buy using the same sandbox account as your seller account_

Comment: THANK YOU. I misunderstood and thought I was creating a new real google account. :)

Comment: The link in the answer labeled "test cards" no longer points to where it did at the time of the answer's writing. I've done some searching around, and it appears that test cards may no longer be supported (if they even ever were). See: https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart/issues/6#issuecomment-164699917

Comment: @TomCatullo Hi - yup, this answer refers to a deprecated product (it was for Wallet "web")

Comment: @EdSF My mistake - I was thinking this would also apply to Android Pay. :)