# Google Wallet payment methods unsupported

Tags: java, android-pay

I'm integrating Google Wallet payments in our website. I have created a merchant and a buyer account and I am testing in different browsers. Practically I did everything as described in the [google wallet tutorial](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial) but the test cards I'm using won't work.

I tried the test cards from [this list](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/testing) and from [this list](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Credit_Card_Test_Cases) but when I add a new payment method to my buyer account it says "Unsupported payment method". But when I test the payment process from the [google wallet tutorial](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial), those same payment methods are available.

For my backend I'm using java and the JWT generation code is the one from the [google wallet tutorial](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial). I replaced the `ISSUER` and `SIGNING_KEY` with my merchant account's `Seller Identifier` and `Seller Secret`. But when I run the code from our website, the payment methods are unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was interesting. Tried it myself and while I can't add a new test card to my [**sandbox buyer account**](https://wallet-web.sandbox.google.com/manage/w/0/#paymentMethods:) directly, using the [IAP demo](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial) allowed me to do so. In the tutorial, just select `"Add a new payment method"` to get any of the test cards to your **sandbox buyer account**.

It wasn't clear in your post but if you notice, I've highlighted **sandbox buyer account** in bold font. You have to use a different sandbox account to test. You can't use the same sandbox account you use as merchant. In other words, use a completely different email address for your **sandbox buyer account**.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17395380/304683) has more detail.

If this isn't the issue, pls include any error message(s)...

Hth.

Comment: I apologize for not specifying, but I have 2 different email addresses for 2 accounts: 1 merchant and 1 buyer. After adding the test card on the IAP demo (not directly on the iframe on our site) it was available on our website. Thanks for the help!